# render partial vs template vs render vs yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and was curious about 'render'

I have a header partial (_header.html.erb) that I placed in the following directory of my Rails app: **app/views/test_results/shared/_header.html.erb**

Now, I want to include my header across different pages. To do this I used `<%= render template: "/test_results/shared/_header"` which works. But if I do `<%= render "/test_results/shared/_header"`or `<%= render partial: "/test_results/shared/_header"` I get an error.

So my questions are:

1. why does **render template** work but not **render** or **render partial**?
2. Is it best-practice the way I am including partials or should I use yield or something else?

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<%= render partial: "/test_results/shared/header" %>` instead of `<%= render partial: "/test_results/shared/_header" %>`. This is because of Rails naming conventions. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials